# Add phone number to existing RingCentral call forwarding Ring Group

Tags: rules, ringcentral

How can a number be appended to an existing RingCentral Ring Group using the REST API? I can't seem to find a way to add a number to a call forwarding RingGroup. I can add it as another forwarding rule, but what I would really like to do is append it to an existing RingGroup.

In the Online Account Portal (https://service.ringcentral.com), creating a Ring Group works by selecting two or more forwarding numbers and clicking "Create Ring Group" as shown below.

[image]

A Ring Group looks like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the RingCentral API, a Ring Group is simply an array of more than one forwarding number in the answering rule of interest. Each answering rule has a `forwarding` property with an array of `forwarding.rules` where each rule has an array of `forwardingNumbers`. The rules are ordered by the 1-based `index` property. A rule with more than one `forwardingNumbers` is a Ring Group.

To add a number, retrieve the current forwarding numbers from the rule of interest and add the forwarding number id of the phone number you want to add to the answering rule.

You can retrieve a list of your answering rules from the `extension/answering-rule` endpoint. The default answering rule ids are below and you can also have custom answering rules.

- `business-hours-rule`: `account/~/extension/~/answering-rule/business-hours-rule`
- `after-hours-rule`: `account/~/extension/~/answering-rule/after-hours-rule`

These are both in the Answering Rules List endpoint:

- API Reference: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefAnsweringRulesList.html

To add an number to a Ring Group, first register it as a forwarding number and then add the forwarding number id to the Ring Group. These are described in the steps below.

**1. Creating a Forwarding Number**

If you don't already have a RingCentral forwarding number for the phone number you want to add, call the `POST extension/forwarding-number` API to create a new forwarding number.

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/forwarding-number

{
  "phoneNumber" : "+12125550100",
  "label" : "Work"
}
```

- API Reference: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefCreateForwardingNumber

**2. Updating an Answering Rule**

The easiest way to add a forwarding number to an existing Ring Group is to call the answering rules endpoint for the rule you wish to update a Ring Group for and then update the rule using the data in the `forwarding` property with the addition of the new forwarding number id. Identify the Ring Group of interest using the `forwarding.rules` array, create an array of existing and new forwardingNumberIds, and then send that as the body of the update request as shown below.

**2.1. Getting the Existing Answering Rule**

Get the `ruleId` you are interested in and then call the following endpoint to get the existing setting:

`/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/answering-rule/{ruleId}`

You will get a JSON object with a number of properties. To update the Ring Group we just need to call the rule endpoint using the `PUT` method with the updated `forwarding` property.

```
# Get Answering Rule Response

GET /restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/answering-rule/business-hours-rule

<snip>

"forwarding": {
  "notifyMySoftPhones": true,
  "notifyAdminSoftPhones": false,
  "softPhonesRingCount": 5,
  "ringingMode": "Sequentially",
  "rules": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "ringCount": 3,
      "forwardingNumbers": [
        {
          "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/11111111/extension/22222222/forwarding-number/33333333",
          "id": "33333333",
          "phoneNumber": "+16505550100",
          "label": "My Phone3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

- API Reference: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefGetAnsweringRule

**2.2 Updating the Answering Rule**

The following is an example of adding the phone number as forwarding rule id `44444444`. You can also update other properties. Additional forwarding properties that can be updated include the following from the response above: `notifyMySoftPhones`, `notifyAdminSoftPhones`, `softPhonesRingCount`, and `ringingMode`.

In the example below, `~` is used for `accountId` and `extensionId`. Here, `~` indicates the current authorizing user, also the user associated with the access token.

```
# Update Answering Rule Request

PUT /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/answering-rule/business-hours-rule

{
  "forwarding": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "index": 1,
        "ringCount": 3,
        "forwardingNumbers": [
          {
            "id": "33333333"
          },
          {
            "id": "44444444"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- API Reference: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefUpdateAnsweringRule

After this, retrieving the answering rule API endpoint will show an array of forwarding numbers and the Online Account Portal will show a Ring Group. The Online Account Portal is available at:

- production - https://service.ringcentral.com
- sandbox - https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com